# How to create different csv files in Python under conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, loops, csv

I have a calculus to do that creates a lot of data. I want to store them into some csv files (without exceed the limits).

```
'''function that gives me 3 values that I want to store'''

import csv
with open('function.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
   writer = csv.writer(file)
   writer.writerow(["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"])
   for x, y, y in function:
     writer.writerow([x, y, z])
```

This code works well but, everytime I exceed the IOPub data rate (or a number, I saw it saves me usually 800k rows), I want to save the next data into others csv file as: functio.csv, function1.csv, function2.csv....

I can do it more or less, but I don't know how not to open thousand times 'open file' or tell to my program 'when the file is "full" for you, use another file'.
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what is your question (i.e. what condition do you want) and what is your issue (i.e. *why* you want this condition)? If by IOPub you mean the Jupyter kernel-client connection, this one should *not* be relevant for the size of data writable to a file. In this case, you might be trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: I want to store some data (millions of rows) but the pickle that I used in a different code stopped storing due to this IOPub issue after "few" rows. I tried different ways, but I dunno how, the csv file is faster. So I want to fill different files in a way to save all my data and manage them kinda easily

Comment: are you generating your data "on the fly" or do you have the results held in some container?  It looks like you have a list of lists in a container called `function`, which is an odd name

Comment: "on the fly", I generate the results with a for loop calling a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count your data and close/reopen your filehandles manually - not using the file context handler.

Make sure to remember to close them all as needed:

```
from itertools import cycle

import csv

# number for name of file
fn = 0

# open 1st file and csv writer on it
fh = open(f"file_{fn}.csv","w", newline="")
csvwriter = csv.writer(fh)

# loop your data (here its simple numbers)
for number in range(35):
    # if certain conditions met
    if number > 0 and number % 5 == 0:
        # close file
        fh.close()
        # increment number 
        fn += 1
        # and open new file  / csv-writer on it
        fh = open(f"file_{fn}.csv","w", newline="")
        csvwriter = csv.writer(fh)

    # write your data
    csvwriter.writerow(["some","data","of",f"line {number}"])

# close last opened file
fh.close()
```

Output:

```
# file_0.csv
some,data,of,line 0
some,data,of,line 1
some,data,of,line 2
some,data,of,line 3
some,data,of,line 4

# file_1.csv
some,data,of,line 5
some,data,of,line 6
some,data,of,line 7
some,data,of,line 8
some,data,of,line 9

# etc.
```